# Bullet Acceleration

Tags: science-based

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question but since it is a science related room, I guess my question will fit. I have looked around the www for a better place to ask this but would like to ask here due to the expected response rate and intellect here.

I'm just curious as to a bullet's claimed acceleration,

The www seems to universally state that a bullet does NOT accelerate after leaving the barrel of a gun. (Claims are that a bullet may possibly only accelerate for .0005 sec after leaving a barrel. If that.)

I'd like to debate that and invite further discussion.

I don't see how a bullet could NOT accelerate upon leaving the barrel since while in the barrel the projectile is faced with great resistance to movement (try pushing a bullet tip through a barrel with a wooden dowel) and once leaving the barrel (resistance) it seems it would accelerate for quite a ways.

Although possibly not an actual question anyone could answer, I welcome comment on this useless knowledge on whether ya'll agree or disagree on whether a bullet would accelerate upon leaving a barrel or not

Comment: Welcome to the site, Stuart. If you aren't familiar with the Stack Exchange model, we're a site where questions receive answers, rather than a discussion forum. That being said, as a purely physics concept, this would be more appropriate on [Physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/). Regardless, your question, as is, does not appear to be on topic here (see the [help](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) and will likely be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Thank You for the welcoming and the heads up. Is there any way this question can  be moderator moved to Physics SE so I don't create duplicate content by posting the same question there?

Comment: I have checked with the Physics moderators and in the question's current form, this is not appropriate there. However, if you edit the question here to meet their standards, including providing evidence of prior research and changing it from "inviting further discussion" to a specific question that can be answered, it may quite well be eligible for migration. See [the Physics SE scope](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The argument "I don't  see how..." is never an argument for anything except one's own lack of insight. Newtonian physics 101: an object will only accelerate if there is a force acting on it. Outside the barrel the only forces are air resistance and gravity, causing the bullet to slow down and drop. So no, the bullet does not accelerate after leaving the barrel.

Comment: Hi @MichaelKarnerfors Does a paperwad forced through a straw accelerate after leaving the straw? Sure seems so... Infact if you put the paper wad at the far end of the straw and give it a good blow it will fly across the room so IT has to be accelerating once leaving the straw (I would think) and I was assuming similar behavior from a bullet leaving a barrel

Comment: @Stuart "Does a paperwad forced through a straw accelerate after leaving the straw?". No, it does not. At most it will get a tiny shove about a centimeter or so after leaving the straw, from air that is coming from it, but this is next to nothing compared to the push it gets while still **in** the straw. And your argument "I think it must be so" is only a bare assertion without any weight. The thing is that gas (which is what pushes the bullet/wad of paper) in the barrel/straw simply disperses in all directions when freed from constraints, and so go **around** the projectile.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors One more time... I'd like to dispute that the paper wad would not accelerate; If you place the paperwad at the far end of the straw (where it exits) and blow, the wad will fly ~10 feet across the room from the pressure (gas) behind it. If it flys 10 ft across the room (when it was only at the end of the barrel to begin with) it seems there has to be some acceleration in there somewhere. I've been under the belief that a bullet would accelerate merely from momentum and loss of restriction. Not just miraculously. I understand your points but I have valid points as well

Comment: @Stuart You have no point to begin with. You just state "It must be the way I say". I say: no, it must not. And not only can I employ Hitchens's Razor on your argument ("That which is asserted without proof can be dismissed without proof") but I can also invoke fundamental laws of physics known since the 1600s, in that you cannot have acceleration out of nothing; there must be a force acting on the object. If you think you  can prove Newton wrong,  I won't even wish you "good luck" in your endeavor, because it is already doomed, and no amount of luck can change that.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors I'm not trying to be difficult and you drive some solid points. You are absolutely correct on the Hitchens Razor comment merely b/c I don't intend on proving the concept (Also nullifying proving Newton wrong which Im not even trying to do). Just try to visualize this regarding the gun example; The bullet is travelling down the barrel facing coarse restriction, building momentum and once free of this restriction with the momentum already achieved that the projectile would accelerate. We could go back and forth for days but it's not worth  it

Comment: Per your comment; "you cannot have acceleration out of nothing; there must be a force acting on the object"I FULLY AGREE. The force acting on the object is the momentum gathered travelling down a restricted path     I'm just adding another variable being sudden loss of restriction with the force and momentum previously discussed being the "force acting on the object". Maybe this is why it's agreed that a bullet would accelerate for .005 seconds. I just thought with the weight of a "bullet" that this would be much greater than .005 second

Comment: @Stuart No I will not visualise that because it is nonsense. Once free of the barrel there are no forces acting on the bullet except air resistance and gravity. The bullet's momentum does not exert a force on the bullet. You are essentially making stuff up out of thin air and imagine that there are physical forces where there are none  (except the aforementioned drag and gravity).

Comment: My bad, I thought that with restricted momentum (in the case of a bullet traveling through a barrel with expanding gases behind it) and loss of restriction that any object would accelerate. The whole discussion can be summed up in that one sentence

Comment: Maybe I should have just put it this way; Does a bullet gain speed (MPH) once leaving the restrictions of the barrel?

Comment: @Stuart Gain speed = accelerate. Acceleration can ONLY happen if a force acts on an object. Newton's First Law of Motion. Once free of the barrel, the only forces acting on a bullet are gravity and air resistance. **Nothing** pushes the bullet forward, so: no, it does not gain any speed. It starts slowing down as soon as it is free of the barrel.

Comment: I just wanted to add my visualization as  it now seems obvious that it wouldn't accelerate with visualizing my following example but I'm still out on whether a clock pendulum swinging accelerates each pass midway or near the end of the down  swing.
If you're in a car on the gas accelerating across deep sand to say 100mph and suddenly hit pavement and throw it in neutral when you hit the pavement, it''s not going to accelerate any further.  I get it now, Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3):

**Bullets do not accelerate after leaving the barrel**

This is easy to prove with little more than a napkin and a pen:

Ask yourself, "what forces are acting on the bullet once it has left the barrel?" Ignore the fraction of a second just afterwards, where the expanding gasses leaving the barrel behind the bullet are still pushing (same as wind pushes a boat), as you stated in your question.

Those only forces are:

- Gravity
- Air resistance

These will provide "acceleration" in the physics sense, as physics makes little distinction between "acceleration" and "deceleration."  Gravity will accelerate the bullet towards the ground and air resistance will provide drag, slowing the bullet.

An *absence* of a force does not miraculously make something go faster!  The friction against the inside of the barrel works to keep the bullet of accelerating more quickly, that is all!  The thing that is causing you confusion  is that you're thinking about something like a car stuck in mud suddenly finding traction and lurching forward.  Bullets do not experience this, as they are not accelerated under their own power, continuing to push forward after the friction of the barrel is gone.  Instead, the opposite is true: the *confined space of the barrel* creates pressure, like a balloon.  Once popped (the bullet leaves the barrel and the expanding gasses escape), that pressure is gone.

If you have a long barreled gun you don't mind taking a hack saw to, and a high-speed camera, you can take measurements yourself firing rounds from it and comparing both before (where the long barrel and the round are correctly matched) and then shortening the barrel and seeing how the shorter chamber (where friction is removed early) affects the final velocity: the shorter barrel will fire slower slugs, because the expanding gasses were released like a popping balloon before their forces had achieved maximum effect (i.e. in the long barrel, the additional force as the volume expands having less impact, causing the bullet to leave the barrel right at the point at which the increased force exactly matches the drag caused by the lengthened barrel).

That said, smart bullets [do exist](http://www.cnn.com/2015/04/29/us/us-military-self-guided-bullet/), which have the capability of propelling themselves forward (or to turn!) after they have left the barrel.  But these are more like tiny, computer-controlled rockets than bullets.

Comment: Awesome Response @Draco18s Thank You so much. You explained this very well. I was thinking that once the bullet broke free of the barrel that the gases behind it would propel it further and enable it to accelerate from being pushed by these gases, not just miraculously accelerate but I think you provided me a visualization with the long vs short barrel and since Im not a physics major, combined with your explanation, I'll just have to believe that it doesn't accelerate after leaving the barrel. Thanks again

Comment: Glad to help, although Frostfyre is correct that this should have been posted over on [Physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/). :)

Comment: See also the forces acting on an airplane: [thrust, drag, lift and weight](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/12155/753).